# Optimization and Indexing on Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Help me on what kind of indexes need to be created and fields to be indexed.
I have tested multiple indexes but still it taking long time to execute

```
db.collection_1.aggregate([{ $match: { $and: [ { date: { $gte: new Date(1593561600000), $lt: new Date(1604966400000) } }, 
{ type: 0 }, { $or: [ { partysr: 0 }, {} ] }, { $or: [ { code: "******" }, { _id: { $type: -1 } } ] } ] } }, 
{ $sort: { date: -1 } }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 100 }, 
{ $lookup: { from: "collection_2", localField: "code", foreignField: "code", as: "j" } }, 
{ $group: { _id: "$codeTsr" } } ]).explain("executionStats")
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave us very little information here.
Have you tried testing this query with and without the $lookup stage?
How does the query behave without lookup speed-wise?
My first guess here is that your collection_2 collection does not have a proper index and it slows query. If your query is much faster without the lookup stage, I would create index on collection_2 for the "code" property.
Also, one more performance optimization might be to first do the $group stage, and after that, you do the $lookup stage.